# Feeding keras with one image (predicting)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I trained a model in Keras (binary image classification, retrained Xception model). Now if I feed it

```
model.predict(np.random.rand(1, 300, 300, 3))
```

I get output

```
array([[0.68225867, 0.3177413 ]], dtype=float32)
```

which is what i'm trying to get with real images. However, when I feed the real image like that:

```
from scipy.misc import imread,imresize
x=imread('processed_dataset/test/EM/bull_212.jpg',mode='RGB')
x=imresize(x,(300,300))
x=np.invert(x)
x=x.reshape(-1,300,300,3)
model.predict(x)
```

I always get the same output:

```
array([[1., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

the model outputs [1., 0] regardless of the input image. It is the same if I feed the image this way:

```
img = image.load_img('processed_dataset/test/EM/bull_212.jpg', target_size=(img_width, img_height))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)


images = np.vstack([x])
model.predict(images, batch_size=1)
```

My thinking is: if feeding a np.random 'image' gives the desired result, the problem is how I feed the real images.
How to do this properly so that it gives me the desired result?

Comment: you have an overfit model, most likely caused by a highle skewed data

Comment: @Inder but I'm giving an image that the model has never seen before, so it should be like random to it. Is my logic wrong?

Comment: its overfit from the data it trained on, so no matter what you give it, it will predict the same result

Comment: Are you applying the same input normalization as the model was trained with?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro the problem was exactly that. Thank you! I didn't do the rescaling part with the input image. If you could post that as an answer, I would mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not applying the normalization that was used to train the model, if you don't do it, then then inputs will be completely different and this will saturate neurons, producing inconsistent outputs.